# MVC 4 Strongly Typed Models in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am beginner working on MVC 4. I have one view which is strongly typed with model with scaffolding template of 'Create'. Now if I modify my model will the view be changed automatically? Or what can be done to have modified view of the model. Deleting previous view and creating new view is also an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing view will not be updated automatically unless you are using [`EditorForModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method within it.